OpenTelemetry: How to prevent multiple messages from sharing the same Trace ID in .NET microservices?
I'm using OpenTelemetry in .NET to send tracing, metrics, and logs to ElasticSearch from my .NET microservices. I'm encountering an issue when publishing multiple messages from a microservice.
For each message, I start tracing (even using StartRootSpan), and on ElasticSearch, the trace for each message in the consumer is captured correctly. However, in the log section, there's confusion: I see logs for all the messages that were sent and processed by the consumer, not just the ones related to the specific trace. It seems like all the messages share the same TraceId, even though the ParentId and SpanId are different.
What’s the best practice to ensure each message has its own TraceId in this scenario?

What do you mean in the first place? And what does the code actually do? In OTEL there's no root span, there's a Trace that includes multiple Spans. All spans in a trace share the same TraceID. What you call message is either a span or a log event, so it makes perfect sense that all the spangs/log events in a trace will have the same TraceID

Besides, in .NET there are no Trace and Span classes. These were implemented by the already existing ActivitySource (for the trace) and Activity (for the span). I strongly suggest looking at .NET Aspire, creating a starter app with dotnet new aspire-starter and looking at the dashboard logs and traces to see what these are supposed to look like, and how a single Trace flows from the front end to the API, containing spans from both. After that, look at the docs and code

After looking at the starter app's dashboard, read the Observability with OpenTelemetry docs. It's a lot easier to understand once you know what to look for. ElasticSearch understands the OTLP protocol which means you don't need special libraries to forward everything to Elastic, you can use AddOtlpExporter.

Hi @PanagiotisKanavos , thank you for answer! exactyl : "What you call message is either a span or a log event, so it makes perfect sense that all the spangs/log events in a trace will have the same TraceID" In this way for each message publish on queue , in the log section of Elasticsearch regarding a trace of single item, i have the logs of all published message , cause they share the same traceid.
